# Rooting and updating the OS for ZTE ZFIVE C LTE

Tags: rooting, zte

How to root a ZTE ZFIVE C LTE (Z558VL) with build number Z558VLHWV1.0?

Comment: Honestly, a quick Google search answers this pretty much through deduction, the Tracfone ZFive is not rootable as it has a locked bootloader and it cannot be unlocked. Although the answer is not given directly, looking at the information (locked bootloader and carrier locked) and understanding modern Android devices, one can deduce that this phone cannot be rooted by normal means. There is some (unverifiable) referenced to Kingroot or WunderShare Tunesgo rooting of this, but those are mostly just C&P spam sites looking for clicks and could find no verifiable example of one that had been done.

Comment: In the modern Android world, rooting is becoming significantly less frequent as it is getting extremely more difficult to do without having a device with an "official" method of doing so, such as a Google Pixel or OnePlus device. The effort involved in creating a rooting method just isn't worth the investment for low-end devices today either, so the ones that do have a root method that isn't "official" are very common, highly sold, devices like mid to upper tier Samsungs or LG's, and root methods are almost unheard of for low-end, locked devices. Sorry.